# SQLite - performing calculation on preceding rows

Tags: sqlite

The problem is this. If I have a quantity in any location, I want to perform the calculation below to each member of that job_no.

The idea is that if there's a quantity in loc3, the same quantity was previously in loc1 and loc2.

So, how do I get 10 in loc1 and loc2 may be another way to put it..?

```
select s.job_no, s.part, s.location, s.qty, 
    coalesce(ptime.setup_time, '-') as setup_time, 
    coalesce(ptime.cycle_time, '-') as cycle_time,
    ci.rate
    from stock as s join part_timings as pt
    on pt.part = s.part
    join locations as l on s.location = l.location
    left join part_timings as ptime on s.part = ptime.part
    and ptime.location = s.location
    join costs_internal as ci
    group by s.part, s.location
    order by s.part, l.stage



job_no | part | location | qty | setup_time | cycle_time | rate | total
123      p1     loc1       0     60           30           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc2       0     30           15           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc3       10    60           15           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc4       0     60           15           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc5       0     60           15           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc6       0     60           15           0.5    ?
123      p1     loc7       20    60           15           0.5    ?
```

calculation to get total:

```
coalesce(round((pt.cycle_time * s.qty * ci.rate) + 
(pt.setup_time * ci.rate), 2), '-')
```

EDIT:

I've added loc4 to loc7.

loc3 would need to have the calculation applied to loc1 and loc2 (qty 10).

loc7 would need to have the calculation applied to all locations that are before it (qty 20).

Maybe I'm not explaining it perfectly, struggle to get my intentions across sometimes with SQL!

Comment: Do you want `qty` to be updated in the table? Or leave them at 0 and just have 10 in the query? And is that for all locations or just ones that are "less than" `loc3`? Would it also go for `loc4`?

Comment: I just need qty for the query, Schwern.

Comment: Sorry, there may be upto loc7. Whichever one has a qty should have the same qty applied to all preceeding locations. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. If you edit your question to show the output you want, as well as the output you have, that would help others to answer. Be sure to include a `loc4` in the sample.

Comment: Will you ever have two locations with a non-zero `qty`? If so, which one gets chosen?

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the extra requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simplified version of your data...

```
select * from stock;

job_no      qty         location  
----------  ----------  ----------
123         0           loc1      
123         0           loc2      
123         10          loc3      
123         0           loc4      
456         0           loc1      
456         20          loc2
```

You can use a sub-select to get the quantity for each job and join with it to get the stock for each job.

```
select stock.*, stocked.qty
from stock
join (select * from stock s where s.qty != 0) as stocked 
  on stock.job_no = stocked.job_no;

job_no      qty         location    qty       
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
123         0           loc1        10        
123         0           loc2        10        
123         0           loc4        10        
123         10          loc3        10        
456         0           loc1        20        
456         20          loc2        20
```

`stocked` has the row for each job which is currently stocked.

Note that unless you've made a restriction, there may be more than one stocked row for a job.

---

> *loc7 would need to have the calculation applied to all locations that are before it (qty 20).*

With this data...

```
sqlite> select * from stock order by job_no, location;
job_no      qty         location  
----------  ----------  ----------
123         0           loc1      
123         0           loc2      
123         10          loc3      
123         0           loc4      
123         0           loc5      
123         0           loc6      
123         20          loc7      
456         0           loc1      
456         20          loc2
```

To accomplish this, instead of joining on the subselect do it on a per column basis else we'll get multiple values stocked locations. (There's probably also a way to do it with a join)

In order to make sure we select only previous locations (or our own) it's necessary to check that `stock.location <= stocked.location`. In order to ensure we get the closest one, order them by location and select only the first one.

```
select stock.*, (
    select stocked.qty
    from stock stocked
    where stock.job_no = stocked.job_no
      and qty != 0
      and stock.location <= stocked.location
    order by stocked.location asc
    limit 1
) as stocked_qty
from stock
order by job_no, location;

job_no      qty         location    stocked_qty
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
123         0           loc1        10         
123         0           loc2        10         
123         10          loc3        10         
123         0           loc4        20         
123         0           loc5        20         
123         0           loc6        20         
123         20          loc7        20         
456         0           loc1        20         
456         20          loc2        20
```

This may be inefficient as a column subselect. It's important that job_no, qty, and location are all indexed.